# How to pull up my Fan Page album images dynamically with Graph API and Jquery

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to pull up my Fan Page album images dynamically with Graph API and Jquery,
without paging , I just need All images URLs + Thumbs URLs

Answer (score 1):

How about trying this:

```
fql?q=SELECT src_big, link, caption FROM photo WHERE album_object_id = YOUR_ALBUM_ID &access_token=ACCESSTOKENOFSOMEONEWHOHASACCESSTOTHOSEPHOTOS
```